# obtain "server side" variable for use in html/javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm trying to develop a language web application. It will scrape data from various websites and ask the participant numerous questions etc. I have created the file that scrapes the web page but I'm having difficulty getting the scraped variables from the `node.js` file. below are some extracts from the node js file:

```
var pword = function() {
    var request = require("request");
    var cheerio = require("cheerio");

    var aa = Math.floor(Math.random() * 588);


    var words = ['abash', 'aberrant', .....]

    var A = words[aa];
    var urlcollinsdictionary = "http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/";
    var Newurldictionary = urlcollinsdictionary + A;
    request({
        uri: Newurldictionary,
    }, function(error, response, body) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(body);

        $('div.homograph-entry').each(function() {
            var link = $(this);
            var text1 = link.text();
            console.log(A);

            console.log(text1);
        });
    });

}
```

My node js code works fine. my problem arises when I try to use its "text1" variable or others of its kind in my `HTML/javascript` coding. I've tried `"getelementbyid"`, `"variable exports/imports"`, even the "%%" method. but still no luck. as you've probably get guess I'm new to programming. please please please help me by making alterations/additions to the HTML code beneath to enable access to the text1 variable and others like it

```
<html>
    <head>
        language game
        <title>language game</title>
        <br>
        <input type = "button" onclick = "word()" value = "Professional Vocab">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            function word(){            
                 alert(text1);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: you need to create an httpserver that can respond to RESTFUL requests and then query from the client javascript to get those variables.

Comment: thanks for the input. again im relatively new to all this. could you give me an idea of what a "httpserver that can respond to RESTFUL requests" would look like or point me in the direction of a beginner friendly manual...thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can add similar code in your node js file to respond to api calls

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
app.get("sendVar", function(request, response){
    response.send(text1);
}
```

you will need to do npm install express in your command line

In your front-end side you can use jquery and make an AJAX call inside function word()

```
function word(){
    $.get("url/sendVar", function(data){
        alert(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks mate....i've just tried your suggestion and it still doesn't work. i've probably not place things in the right place. is there a specific location in the coding that your code must be placed within the coding?

Comment: for this to work you first need to install express. for this in the console, please run **npm install express** and then require express as above

Comment: i did that as per your original comment. any other ideas as to why its not working..